# Python: How to traverse a list of lists by columns, as if it was a regular 2D array (matrix)?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, matrix

I have a list of lists like this:
`list=[[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15]]`.

I want to use this list in a function that "slices" my `list` into `9` groups of four values each, that are dumped into a `dict` of `lists`. If `len(list)=n`, the function should create `[sqrt(n)-1]*[sqrt(n)-1]` slices. In this case, given `len(list)=16`, `slices=[4-1]*[4-1]=9`.

This is the function:

```
def dictionarize1(array):
    dict1 = {}
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(array[0]) - 1) :
        for y in range(len(array[0]) - 1):
            dict1[count] = [array[x][y], array[x][y+1], array[x+1][y], array[x + 1][y+1]]
            count = count + 1
    return dict1 


dictionarize1(list) #Calling the function
```

I think of my `list` as a 2D array - a `4x4` matrix in this case - which must be traversed as if it was a matrix: the `row` is fixed and the `column` is incremented:

```
Columns ->
Rows v    0    1    2    3
          4    5    6    7
          8    9    10   11
          12   13   14   15
```

Therefore, my slices must be `[0,1,4,5]`, `[1,2,5,6]`,`[2,3,6,7]`,`[4,5,8,9]` etc., **without wrapping the matrix up.**

The final result should be `dict={'0':[0,1,4,5],'1':[1,2,5,6],'2':[2,3,6,7],'3':[4,5,8,9],'4':[5,6,9,10],'5':[6,7,10,11],'6':[8,9,12,13],'7':[9,10,13,14],'8':[10,11,14,15]}`.

**My question:**  is this the correct way for my `for` loops to traverse the list by columns (which means: the row is fixed, the column is incremented)? I cannot judge as if I print my `list` I only get a regular list so it confuses me. Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be worthwhile spending some time refining your question. It might just be me, but I can't tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not very much experienced. I just want to figure out if the list is traversed by columns as I want or by rows. And if it does it by rows, I would like to know how to change this.

Comment: Shouldn't your ranges go to `sqrt(len(array))` it just happens to work in this case because the matrix is 4x4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I understand what you want. If you want to show correct results do this

```
list = dictionarize1(list) #Calling the function
print(list) #your result is ok
```